# Array of byte arrays

Tags: java, eclipse, arrays

My app gets a sequence of images, compresses each image with jpeg algorithm, which are stored as a byte arrays(1 img = 1 byte[]). Then it collects all the byte arrays into one array(just like matrix), but java compiler(or eclipse) says that it doesn't work. Here is the code of how I set the byte array into another byte array.

```
CompressedImage frameArrayElement = new CompressedImage(video.frame[i]);
byte[] currentFrame = frameArrayElement.compress(video.frame[i]);
package.setFrame(currentFrame, i);
```

And this is the code of function setFrame().

```
void setFrame(byte[] f, int i) {
    frames[i] = f;
}
```

Eclipse tells me about type mismatch and suggests switching "byte[] f" tot "byte f".

How should I sort this out?

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `frames` field.

Comment: How is `frames` declared? What's the exact and complete error message? Don't you think this information might help understanding what the problem is?

Comment: frames is an array, if you didn't notice. No offence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this assignment to work, `frames` needs to be declared as `byte[][]` in the class that has the `setFrame` method:

```
private byte[][] frames;
```

From the error that you posted it appears that `frames` is declared as `byte[]`, not as `byte[][]`. That's why the compiler suggests making `f` a `byte`.

Comment: @PeterChudinov You are welcome! Since this worked for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.